# Есть ли подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис

Пожалуйста, скажите, есть ли подлежащее в следующих предложениях (или они являются безличными):
У мальчиков есть вода.
Перед ними расстилалось море.
У брата журнал.

Буду очень признателен за ответ.

Я кончил школу в 1951 году. 14 лет живу в Америке. Учительница английского, у которой я учился, начала изучать русский язык. В споре со своей подругой она утверждает, что "вода" в первом предложкнии является подлежащим. Я выбран арбитром, но я сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Oleg, если хотите уточнить вопрос, то отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 7):

Первые два предложения двусоставные полные : вода есть, море расстилалось. Последнее предложение двусоставное неполное. Опущено сказуемое есть. Дополнение "У брата" зависит от сказуемого, а не от подлежащего.

Comment: Большое спасибо за быстрый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Oleg, на вопрос Вам ответили, я могу только присоединиться к Ларf.
Но, если позволите, два слова по самой ситуации.
Я полагаю, вопреки даже мнению авторов некоторых пособий, что, изучая русский как иностранный, не стоит увлекаться грамматическим разбором подобных фраз. Та из подруг, которая сомневается в том, что вода - подлежащее, тоже по-своему права. 
На смысловом уровне наше подлежащее (вода) на самом деле является не субъектом действия (что в английском было бы непреложной истиной), а объектом, а дополнение - наоборот. И при переводе таких фраз на английский дополнение и подлежащее "меняются местами".  
Учительница должна понять это заклинание.

Поэтому лучше всего не искать подлежащие в непривычных типах предложения, а развивать понимание того, что русское "Я" вполне может соответствовать не только "I", но и "I аm", конструкция "У меня есть" дает английское подлежащее и сказуемое "I have" и проч.

А поиски главных членов в "нестандартном" русском предложении - это уже уровень как минимум студентов-филологов. К тому же я не уверен, что умные дяди еще раз не передумают, пока ваши знакомые будут учить русский. С момента окончания Вами школы академический взгляд на подобные проблемы поменялся раз несколько.

Comment: Очень благодарен Вам за Ваш совет. Я передам его участникам спора.

Answer (score 0):

У мальчиков есть вода.- Подлежащее "вода" обозначает предмет речи. Сказуемое - "есть"(имеется).
 Перед ними расстилалось море.- Подлежащее - "море", сказуемое - "расстилалось".
 У брата журнал.- Подлежащее - "журнал", сказуемого нет. Это односоставное назывное предложение

Comment: Предложение "У брата журнал" не может быть односоставным назывным, там есть состав сказуемого - "у брата"-обстоятельство со значением дополнения. Если есть обст-во, то предложение неполное двусоставное.

Comment: Больщое спасибо за ясный и полный ответ.