# Какое сказуемое в предложении "У Лены две ноги"?

Tags: синтаксис

> У Лены две ноги.

- *две ноги* - подлежащее
- *у Лены* - дополнение

А сказуемое какое?

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то об этом спорят давно и безрезультатно. 
Если не ошибаюсь, сейчас в школе предлагают считать "есть" (в "[есть] две ноги") опущенным сказуемым.

Вот здесь посмотрите подробно.

[Есть ли подлежащее?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21711)

А вот в теоретической грамматике склонны вообще относить подобные предложения к особому типу предложений ("эргативному"), где нет понятия подлежащего и сказуемого, а есть только объекты-субъекты производителя и получателя действия (агенса и пациенса), причем оба могут находится как бы в косвенных падежах. Но такой тип синтаксиса вообще-то русскому языку не свойственен, поэтому для учащихся находят более простое толкование с опущенным сказуемым.

Противоречивость этой идеи хорошо видна на примере с заменой "есть" на "имеется": *"У меня имеется две ноги"*. Предложение грамматически то же, но тут-то "две ноги" никак не подлежащее, ибо сказуемое с ним не согласовано. Но это отдельный разговор.

Comment: Немного офф-топик. Когда просишь человека, начинающего изучать английский, перевести это предложение (_Lena has two legs._) - первый вопрос: "Как по-английски будет предлог У". Стал объяснять, что в русском *две ноги* подлежащее и споткнулся, не найдя сказуемого.

Comment: *Как по-английски будет предлог У*  - Это не вопрос. ***At Lena's (there are) two legs***. Это буквальный  перевод, рекомендуемый самими носителями английского как подстрочник. Небольшая инверсия не воспринимается как грубое нарушение грамматики. Можно и без притяжательного падежа ("аt me", например, вместо "at mine"), но притяжательный здесь лучше: он передает тонкость русской конструкции собственности. Только всё это больше как раз для изучающих русский иностранцев, русскому-то проще запомнить простые английские конструкции без наворотов: ***"у X  есть Y" = "X has Y"*** - и точка.

Comment: "У меня имеется две ноги". Имеется, имеются – одно и то же, поэтому подлежащее, несомненно, "две ноги".

Comment: *Имеется, имеются – одно и то же* - ну, знаете... А грамматика для Вас - как для Митрофанушки?

Comment: >> *"У меня имеется две ноги". Предложение грамматически то же, но тут-то "две ноги" никак не подлежащее, ибо сказуемое с ним не согласовано*. Где сказано, что сказуемое должно быть "согласовано"? Примеров, где "не согласовано" -- мильён. Есть целый раздел в справочнике, называется "Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим". behemothus, вы на себя не похожи. ))

Comment: Не надо примеров. Теорию давайте, где сказано, что не должно быть согласовано - и в каких случаях. И я первый вам сказал недели две назад, что после вашего возвращения из небытия вижу в вас совершенно другого человека, раньше вы были куда более конструктивным и аккуратным в формулировках.

Comment: Зачем теория, когда полно примеров из живой и, прошу заметить, *грамотной* речи?

Comment: Niemand, это это край, после которого я вынужден буду отправить Вас учить матчасть.  Вы ссылаетесь на учебники, предлагаете мне их читать - и тут же утверждаете, что Вам-то теория ни к чему?!

Comment: >> *Теорию давайте, где сказано, что не должно быть согласовано - и в каких случаях.* Так вы прочитали раздел "Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим"? Теорию просите, а сами не читаете...

Comment: Нет, я не считаю нужным что-то перечитывать по Вашим указаниям. Когда человек, который не в состоянии внятно изложить суть своих замечаний, посылает меня читать учебники, я рассматриваю как троллинг. Типа, а "вдруг и правда там что-то есть". )))